# ¿Cómo utilizar varios ActionResult en una misma vista?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación MVC.NET en C#. Dentro de un controlador tengo dos ActionResult de tipo [HttpPost] que realizan diferentes acciones. He creado una vista a partir del primer ActionResult que elabore.

Y dentro de esa vista he logrado cumplir con lo requerido, mi problema es con el segundo método ActionResult que me sugiere crear una nueva vista, ¿es obligatorio crear una vista por método ActionResult?

Pregunto esto porque todo el diseño que requiere mi vista web ya lo he elaborado en la primera vista que diseñe. Ambos métodos son llamados por botones de tipo submit, el primero logra hacer lo que necesito dentro de la web, cuando presiono el segundo botón me manda a mi segundo método (a través de un punto de interrupción) pero no me muestra el modelo que tengo ahí, además de no reconocerme una vista.

Parte de mi código de mi segundo método:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CargarSQLServer(CargaArchivo modelDocumentoSQL)
    {
        if(modelDocumentoSQL.Documento != null && modelDocumentoSQL.Documento.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            //si viene la información completa, usar la siguiente instrucción
            var ListOpexBanco = new List<PRUEBAOPEX>();
            foreach (var item in modelDocumentoSQL.listVMOpexBanco)
            {
                PRUEBAOPEX model = new PRUEBAOPEX() { 
                    LINEAMC = item.LineaMc,
                    LINEANIVEL2 = item.LineaNivel2,
                    LINEANIVEL3 = item.LineaNivel3,
                };
                ListOpexBanco.Add(model);
            }

            db.BulkInsert(ListOpexBanco);
            //Fin


             }
        }
        return View(modelDocumentoSQL);
    }
```

Botones de mi vista:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El botón de vista previa se encarga de cargar los registros mostrados en la parte superior, al seleccionar el botón procesar datos me lleva al segundo método.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posterior a este breakpoint, me sale el error que les comente. ¿Cómo puedo corregir esa parte sin necesidad de crea una nueva vista? Ya que no tengo nada más que diseñar, hacer ambos métodos en esa misma vista.

De antemano, muchas gracias por la atención.

Comment: Si luego de procesar  botón `ProcesarDatos ` debe quedarse en la misma vista entonces en CargarSqlServer no retornes la vista sino haces un RedirectToAction("PrimeraVista"), entonces este método lo deriva a la primera acción que es la que sabe como armar la vista que se encuentra actualmente activa. Espero hacerme entender. Lógicamente  cuando haces elvredict a la primera acción tienes que pasarte los parámetros si los hubiera, por ejemplo si la primera acción es "Index": RedirectToAction("Index") adicialnalm3n63 pudes poner el controller ey parametros

Comment: No es obligatorio, y no existe una relación 1-1 entre vista y modelo. Un ActionResult puede retornar varias cosas, entre ellas vistas, y 2 o más ActionResult pueden retornar la misma vista, para ello debes colocar `return View("nombre_vista",modelo)`

Comment: Muchas gracias @Yussef y Juan Carlos. Pude resolver mi problema.

Comment: Podrías comentar la solución o inclusive ponla como solución de manera que pueda ayudar a otras personas que quizás tengan casos similares.

Comment: Este workshop te será de ayuda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY&list=PL-_pdwtmHN2TcXVCoDc0qSqzwRFgJarO_&index=13 Tiene todos los fundamentos de ASPnet MVC5 y aunque quizás estés utilizando aspnet core, los conceptos son los mismos. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo pude resolver, retornando mi primera vista desde el segundo ActionResult de mi controlador.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CargarSQLServer(CargaArchivo modelDocumento)
    {
            var ListOpexBanco = new List<PRUEBAOPEX>();
            foreach (var item in modelDocumento.listVMOpexBanco)
            {
                PRUEBAOPEX model = new PRUEBAOPEX() { 
                    LINEAMC = item.LineaMc,
                    LINEANIVEL2 = item.LineaNivel2,
                    LINEANIVEL3 = item.LineaNivel3,
                };
                  ListOpexBanco.Add(model);
             }
                

                db.BulkInsert(ListOpexBanco);

                return View("CargarArchivo", modelDocumento);
    }
```